# Why is Scipy's KDTree so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kdtree

Let's say I have around 100 sets of 100 points and want to find out which points are within a given distance of each other. I have two implementations of this, one using a k-d Tree and the other simply getting pairwise distances:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from itertools import combinations
import numpy
import time

pts = [numpy.random.randn(100,2) for x in range(100)]


start = time.time()

for p1, p2 in combinations(pts,2):
    numpy.argwhere(cdist(p1, p2) < 0.5)

print(time.time() - start)


start = time.time()

trees = [KDTree(x) for x in pts]

for p1, p2 in combinations(trees,2):
    p1.query_ball_tree(p2,0.5,eps=1)

print(time.time() - start)
```

On my machine `cdist` takes 0.5 seconds whilst the `KDTree` implementation takes an entire minute. Building the trees takes 0.03 seconds. I would expect the `KDTree` method to be faster since it doesn't need to consider every possible pair of points.

So, what have I misunderstood, and can this be done faster?

Comment: Is it possible that building the trees implies an overhead that is not amortized given the relatively small sizes of your data?
Insert a `print(time.time() - start)` after `trees = ...`  to know

Comment: Tree building takes 0.032 seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pure python. The alternative implementation, cKDTree, is much faster.

Comment: Trying my code again with `cKDTree` gives equivalent or faster performance compared to `cdist`. Thanks!